# losing first data element jquery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tablednd

I am having a problem that I cannot figure out.

I am using the tableDND jQuery add in, which allows me to drag and drop rows of a table.  I want to send those rows to the server and have them uploaded to a mySQL database.

My code is below, basically when I get to the PHP the first element of the batting variable is gone.  Any ideas?

So I have the following javascript:

```
$('#order').tableDnD({
        onDrop: function(table, row) {

            var batting = $.tableDnD.serialize();
            var id = <?php echo $id;?>;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'update_batting.php',
                data: '{ "batting":' + batting + ', "id":'+ id +' }',
                dataType: 'json',
            });

        }
    });
```

and the following php:

```
<?php

$batting = json_encode($_POST['order']);

$query = "INSERT INTO test (t) VALUES ('$batting')";
mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Comment: did you assign data: {order: '{ "batting":' + batting + ', "id":'+ id +' }'}? Otherwise I don't know how $_POST['order'] would return anything

Comment: $_POST['order'] comes back as 100245,100007,100296,100213,100071,100125,110206,110205,100152,100247,100329,100299,100243, "id":662852670 } the data in the ajax is { "batting":order[]=110209&order[]=100245&order[]=100007&order[]=100296&order[]=100213&order[]=100071&order[]=100125&order[]=110206&order[]=110205&order[]=100152&order[]=100247&order[]=100329&order[]=100299&order[]=100243, "id":662852670 }

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com) you've got there.

Comment: I'm sure this is for ease of use. Only a fool would just blindly accept post data. Besides, it's being json_encoded... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is my crude guess at this one since I have to go soon...

I think since "data" is converted to a query string it is being misread.
I think your post is probably reading this:

```
$_POST['batting'] = 'order[]=110209';
$_POST['order'] = 'order[]=100245&order[]=100007&order[]=100296&order[]=10‌​0213&order[]=100071&order[]=100125&order[]=110206&order[]=110205&order[]=100152&o‌​rder[]=100247&order[]=100329&order[]=100299&order[]=100243';
$_POST['id'] = '662852670';
```

Because the first occurrence of the ampersand is terminating your variable.

It might seem silly, but you can probably escape this whole problem by surrounding "batting" with double quotes. Effectively containing it as a string.

```
data: '{ "batting":"' + batting + '", "id":'+ id +' }',
```

This would change your expected $_POST['order'] variable to "$_POST['batting']
However, your data object should be contained like I originally mentioned in the comment above.

```
data: {order: '"' + batting + '"', id:id},
```

Instead of sending it as a string with no key as in your sample code.

Try var_dump($_POST) in php to see all values you're getting... just out of curiosity.

**Sorry for all the edits. I'm being distracted constantly at work...

Comment: no worries... this basically worked; now the output in the php for $_POST['order'] is order[]=110209&order[]=100245&order[]=100007&order[]=100296&order[]=100213&order[]=100071&order[]=100125&order[]=110206&order[]=110205&order[]=100152&order[]=100247&order[]=100329&order[]=100299&order[]=100243 which is all the elements; now all i need to do is get the order[] outta there so i can put just the numbers in the database... it was only sending the numbers before

Comment: It's cause it is now a literal string. It might be ghetto but you could explode on order[]= to return an array of the numbers, and that extra ampersand that would also need to be trimmed. $array = array(); $order = explode("order[]=", $_POST['order']); foreach($order AS $o){ $array[] = str_replace("&", "", $o); }

Answer (score -1):

Have you tryed to remove the spaces on each side of  ' + batting + ' ....
like '+ batting +'....

Comment: Shouldn't matter. he could have 10 spaces after that single quote and it would still be an append statement.

Comment: I pass variable as post with JS for ajax and if i leave the spaces there they show up in the post request. So my vars had space in it. And the other problem was the DOM the php file dealing with that Post was in the wrong format and i was loosing the first Var becuse of that as well. Just pointing that out